# Prove that $D:C^1[0,1]\to C[0,1]$ is not continuous.

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification

Let $C^1[0,1]$ be the space of continuous real valued functions on $[0,1]$ with continuous first derivative. Let $D:C^1[0,1]\to C[0,1]$ be the differentiation operator given by $D(f)(x)=f^\prime(x),\forall x\in [0,1]$. Suppose both spaces are given the sup norm $\|.\|_\infty$. Now it is required to prove that $D$ is not continuous. The following is my attempt:

$D$ is a linear operator by the properties of differentiation. Hence $D$ is continuous if and only if $D$ is bounded on $C^1[0,1]$. Suppose $D$ is bounded. Then there exists $k>0$ such that for each $f\in C^1[0,1]$, $\|D(f)(x)\|_\infty\leq k\|f(x)\|_\infty$, i.e. $\|f'(x)\|_\infty\leq k\|f(x)\|_\infty$. Consider the function $g(x)=\sin(357kx)$ for each $x\in[0,1]$. Clearly $g\in C^1[0,1]$. Therefore $357k\leq\|g'(x)\|_\infty\leq k\|g(x)\|_\infty \leq k.1=k$ which is a contradiction. Therefore $D$ is not bounded and hence not continuous.

Could someone please tell me if my argument is correct? Thanks.

Comment: OK. -- Alternatively (and more directly, if you will), $f_n(x)=\frac1n\sin nx$ tends $\to 0$ in $\infty$-norm, but $f_n'=\cos nx$ does not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your argument correct. But why $357$? Why not just $2$, for instance?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I like 357 as my username might suggest.

Comment: @Janitha357 Well, that's a good reason ineed.